# How to read a sequence of numbers and stop the data entry by entering -1?

Tags: python-2.7

Develop the code to read a sequence of numbers entered by the user and display it. The user is told to enter the number -1 to indicate the end of data entry.

```
 input_list = raw_input('Enter sequence of numbers and enter -1 to indicate the end of data entry: ')

 list = input_list.split()
 list = [int(a) for a in input_list:if(a == -1): break]

 print 'list: ',list
```

I am expecting to get:

ex1)Enter sequence of numbers and enter -1 to indicate the end of data entry: 1 3 5 -1 6 2

list: [1, 3, 5]

ex2)Enter sequence of numbers and enter -1 to indicate the end of data entry: 1 3 5 2 4 -1 2 6 2

list: [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]

However and of course, the code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function split twice. The first split will allow you to stop at the first "-1", the second will allow you to differenciate the numbers :

```
input_list = raw_input('Enter sequence of numbers and enter -1 to indicate the end of data entry: ')

numbers = input_list.split('-1')[0].split(' ')[:-1]
print(numbers)
```

---

```
# With  : 1 3 5 -1 6 2
Out [1] : ['1', '3', '5']
# With 1 3 5 2 4 -1 2 6 2
Out [2] : ['1', '3', '5', '2', '4']
```

*Side note* : Be careful list is a protected variable name in python

Comment: Holy moly! Thank you so much!